# Font blurred/symbolized when exporting to pdf CR2008

Tags: pdf-generation, crystal-reports-2008

I've got yet another problem with Crystal Reports 2008. This time, when I'm exporting to PDF from CR2008 from the company server, a font, Dax-regular, gets blurry. It's not completely illegible, but it is smudged out, like the ink got wet.

Another problem is that certain fonts, which I am sure are not DRM-protected or anything like that, when exported are random gibberish symbols, not readable text. This seems to be a problem with the embedding of fonts in CR.

I believe the smudged fonts could be caused by a fix I had to perform because of the small text bug that others have reported (http://www.arcanadev.com/support/kb/K00000394.aspx).

What can I do to troubleshoot and, if possible, fix this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: can you supply a sample PDF illustrating your issue?

Answer (score 0):

To my experience I haven't seen anything like that all fonts are properly exported to PDF if you provide any screenshot it would be more helpful.
Your second issue of symbols there are some fonts when you type will provide you symbols may be you are using those....
Sorry if I understood yout issue in a wring way